# Disable Maven SCM

Tags: maven-2, maven-scm

Could I disable SCM integration option in Maven? I want it to build a local checked-out project without SCM integration ?

is there some settings or some how??

thanx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "without SCM integration"? What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCM integration is only used when you want to [release](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) a new version of software or generate [changelog](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/). When build a local checked-out project SCM integration is "ignored".

There is also [scm-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/)  but it isn't binded to none of the default lifecycles.

**EDIT**
According [pom reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM) if you declare scm section it must be valid otherwise remove scm section.
Please paste your scm section or maybe scm plugin is used in pom.

Comment: but it complains with: java.lang.NullPointerException: The scm url cannot be null. at org.apache.maven.scm.manager.AbstractScmManager.makeScmRepository(AbstractScmManager.java:181) at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getScmRepository(CreateMojo.java:722) at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getScmBranch(CreateMojo.java:593) at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute(CreateMojo.java:452) ...

Comment: Then I would assume that your POM is invalid. Either define a SCM entry (and you could choose to give it a dummy url, if you don't know the real repository) or leave that configuration out.

Comment: i too am facing the same issue..when i remove the scm section from my pom i get the error : "scm url cannot be null" . I am using buildnumber-plugin 1.0.4 beta

Answer (score 10):

You should check if you're using Buildnumber Maven plugin.

By default and recommended configuration it is set to be invoked on "validate" phase of every build and will fail the build with this message.

If it is the case you have two options:

1. Disable the use of this plugin (by removing it from POM or moving it into special profile)
2. Add scm section as described above.

Hope this helps!