# maven build error

Tags: java, maven-2, version-control, maven-scm

when building a maven project. i am getting the following error.

```
[ERROR]Runtime Exception thrown during execution
[ERROR]The scm url cannot be null.
```

Please hint me on how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It is not clear what goal you are executing but the error looks self explaining: you need to add a [SCM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM) element:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/svn/my-project</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/svn/my-project</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>http://127.0.0.1/websvn/my-project</url>
  </scm>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
[Disable Maven SCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751987/disable-maven-scm)

What's in your pom.xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to a missing developerConnection in the SCM section of your POM. This can lead to the (misleading) error message you are reporting: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1014

It would help if you could post a copy of your POM and the goal you are trying to execute.